# How can I get the Style Name of a vsf file (VCL Style file)?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles

I have an application written  in delphi-xe2, now i'm adding VCL styles support, So i want to build a menu to choose the vcl style file to load and apply, this part is working fine , the menu is build in runtime based in the content of a folder which has the style files. But now I want to display the name of the vcl style instead of filename just like this image

[image]

How I can get the name of the style of an vcl style file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`TStyleManager.IsValidStyle`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Themes.TStyleManager.IsValidStyle) function, passing a [`TStyleInfo`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/Themes.TStyleInfo) record which return this and another info related to the vcl style.

Check this sample app

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Vcl.Styles,
  Vcl.Themes;

var
 Style : TStyleInfo;
begin
  try
    if TStyleManager.IsValidStyle('C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\9.0\Styles\RubyGraphite.vsf', Style) then
    begin
       Writeln(Format('Name           %s',[Style.Name]));
       Writeln(Format('Author         %s',[Style.Author]));
       Writeln(Format('Author EMail   %s',[Style.AuthorEMail]));
       Writeln(Format('Author URL     %s',[Style.AuthorURL]));
       Writeln(Format('Version        %s',[Style.Version]));
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  readln;
end.
```